# Unable to insert Danish text in sqlite3 with proper format

Tags: ios, sqlite

Hello freinds i am trying to insert some danish text in my table of sqlite3 db and for that i m inserting it as...

```
NSString  *sqlTemp =[NSString stringWithFormat:
  @"INSERT INTO myTable (firstArg,secondArg,thirdArg,fourthArg) VALUES ('%@','%@','%@','%@')",
  txt1,text2,txt3,txt4];
const char *sql = [sqlTemp UTF8String];
```

type of all arguements while creating table is declared as "text".

the issue is when i retreive the data from db and want to set as text of uitextview it is diplaying somthing like `"√Ö√¶√∏√¶"` for danish text `"Åæøæ"`

Can any one suggest some solution for this .

Thanks in advance

Paggyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the sqlite3_bind_text function which binds your text using its UTF8 representation, check the answer of [Storing and retrieving data from sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147519/storing-and-retrieving-data-from-sqlite-database/8147921#8147921), where you can find a complete example of how to insert such data into a database.

Answer (score 0):

Set your datatype to nvarchar.

Comment: setting datatype to nvarchar doesn't help any other suggestion